# Crowd-plugin on new UserCreateEvent

Tags: atlassian-plugin-sdk, atlassian-crowd

I want to start to develop a crowd-plugin. The plugin has to connect to an AD search a user and get a specific property of AD. So I started to follow this . I already had the Atlassian-SDK installed for a JIRA-plugin that I developped in the past. So I created a new plugin with

```
atlas-create-crowd-plugin
```

and after I erased the class that the create command created form me and copied in the example code, but this didn't work (compiling problems). So I changed a litle bit the pom.xml

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0        
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <organization>
            <name>Example Company</name>
            <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
        </organization>

    <name>event-listener-example</name>
        <description>This is an event listener plugin for Atlassian Crowd.</description>

    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.atlassian.crowd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>crowd-events</artifactId>
                    <version>${crowd.version}</version>
                    <cope>provided</scope>
            <dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.event</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-event</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-crowd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.2.1</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>
                                <productVersion>${crowd.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${crowd.data.version}</productDataVersion>
                        </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        <configuration>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
     </build>
     <properties>
    <crowd.version>2.8.4</crowd.version>
        <crowd.data.version>2.8.4</crowd.data.version>
    <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}  </atlassian.plugin.key>
    </properties>
 </project>
```

Here you can see that I cahnged It a litle bit (versions, and added the atlassian-event dependency).

Then I changed the atlassian-plugin.xml :

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${atlassian.plugin.key}" name="${project.name}" 
    plugins-version="2">  
    <plugin-info>  
        <description>${project.description}</description>  
        <version>${project.version</version>  
        <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" 
            url="${project.organization.url}" />  
        <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>  
        <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param>  
    </plugin-info>  
    <resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="kgSynchro" />  
    <listener name="User Created Listener" key="usercreatedlistener"  
        class="myPackage.NewUserEventListener">  
        <description>Will listen for user creation 
             events.</description>  
    </listener>  
</atlassian-plugin>
```

And at the end my class:

```
package myPackage.events;
import org.slf4j.Logger; 
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; 
import com.atlassian.crowd.event.user.UserCreatedEvent; 
import com.atlassian.event.api.EventListener; 
public class NewUserEventListener {  
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger                  (NewUserEventListener.class);  

    @EventListener  public void printUserCreatedEvent(
        UserCreatedEvent event) {  
            System.out.println("User " + event.getUser                      ().getDisplayName() + " has been created.");  
            log.error("new User is CREATED"); 
    } 
}
```

Same that the example but I added the Logger to log the call of the method.

Then I started the crod environment with atlas-run (also tried the atlas-debug), and I went to the User UI and tried to add a New User. The user was created correctly, but on the log notthing appear about my method. I have a lot of errors about:

```
 The Struts dispatcher cannot be found. This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
```

But this happens on evry page that I navigate on crowd..... then I thnik this is not relevant on the fact that my method is never called.

Has every one some tips about what to try to find out the problem?

Tank's very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

The path of your listener is "myPackage.events.NewUserEventListener".
Change your atlassian-plugin.xml listener section to the below code.

```
<listener name="User Created Listener" key="usercreatedlistener"  
    class="myPackage.events.NewUserEventListener">  
    <description>Will listen for user creation events.</description>  
</listener>
```

Also, it's good to practice [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).
Hope this may help you.

Thanks,

Vikash